# How to set public variable dynamically when a class instance is created

Tags: php, class

When I initialize a new class instance I want to set a public variable based on the current url.

How do I go about setting the public variable dynamically when the class instance is created so it is available without having to call a function.

```
 class CONFIGURATOR{
    static public $ACTIVE = true;
    public $CURRENT_URL="<current_url here>"
  }
```

Comment: You are unclear with your question, but you can either populate that variable via constructor when you're creating the object or after you created the object via `$obj->CURRENT_URL = 'your url'`;

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor :

```
class CONFIGURATOR{
   static public $ACTIVE = true;
   public $CURRENT_URL="<current_url here>"

   public function __construct($url)
   {
       $this->CURRENT_URL = $url;
   }
}
```

You can call your object like this :

```
$configurator = new CONFIGURATOR($your_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor , it may be solve your problem

```
class CONFIGURATOR{
    static public $ACTIVE = true;
    public $CURRENT_URL="";

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->$CURRENT_URL="<current_url here>";
    }
  }
```

Thank You